# añadir evento keypress (enter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Estimados tengo esta función que carga data de un json con el evento click en el button funciona bien, necesito que también lo haga con la tecla enter usando keypress, no he podido añadirle ese evento pueden ayudarme.
Gracias

```html
<form class="form">
<input class="search" type="search" name="search" id="search" required>
<input type="button" name="btnSearch" id="btnSearch" value="Buscar">
</form>
```

```js
$('#btnSearch').click(function() {
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');

    $.getJSON('/books-schema.json', function(data) {
        var output = '<ul id="resultado">';

        $.each(data.data, function(key, item) {
            if ((item.title.search(myExp) != -1) || (item.teaser.search(myExp) != -1)) {
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<span class="image"><img src=' + item.image + '/></span>';
                output += '<span class="title">' + '<h3>' + item.title + '</h3>' + '</span>';
                output += '<span class="description">' + '<p>' + item.teaser + '</p>' + '</span>';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('content').html(output);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con este código :

```
$('#search').keypress(function(e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        Buscar();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});

$('#btnSearch').click(function() {
    Buscar();
});

function Buscar() {
var searchField = $('#search').val();
var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');

$.getJSON('/books-schema.json', function(data) {
    var output = '<ul id="resultado">';

    $.each(data.data, function(key, item) {
        if ((item.title.search(myExp) != -1) || (item.teaser.search(myExp) != -1)) {
            output += '<li>';
            output += '<span class="image"><img src=' + item.image + '/></span>';
            output += '<span class="title">' + '<h3>' + item.title + '</h3>' + '</span>';
            output += '<span class="description">' + '<p>' + item.teaser + '</p>' + '</span>';
            output += '</li>';
        }
    });
    output += '</ul>';
    $('content').html(output);
});

}
```

Saludos,

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta, creo que no explique bien, necesito añadirle a la función también funcione con la tecla enter, no debo quitar el click debe funcionar con ambos eventos (click, y enter)

Comment: deja los dos eventos, y para que no repitas código, mueve la lógica interna hacia una funcion que llamas desde los dos eventos...

Comment: ok puse los 2 eventos, el problema que presento es que con el enter no muestra resultado lo que hace es refrescar la pagina y no carga data. poniendo la misma palabra, el botón si la muestra.

Comment: bueno, metiendo la lógica a una función ya el enter muestra la data pero sigo teniendo el problema que refresca la pagina y al refrescar borra el contenido mostrado ¿por que con el enter me refresca la pagina? Gracias

Comment: Prueba con  preventdefault y return false; en el keypress, tal y como quedo despues de editado el codigo.

Comment: lo que hace es cambiar la url muestra http://localhost:8089/?search=texto, eso hace que refresque la pagina ¿por que cambia la url por que sucede esto.? Gracias

Comment: ok Gracias el return false era el problema añadiéndole al keypress funciono gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta, gracias!.

Answer (score 1):

el Código final me quedo así, por si alguien le sirve
Gracias.

```js
function Cargardata () {
 var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');

    $.getJSON('/books-schema.json', function(data) {
        var output = '<ul id="resultado">';

        $.each(data.data, function(key, item) {
            if ((item.title.search(myExp) != -1) || (item.teaser.search(myExp) != -1)) {
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<span class="image"><img src=' + item.image + '/></span>';
                output += '<span class="title">' + '<h3>' + item.title + '</h3>' + '</span>';
                output += '<span class="description">' + '<p>' + item.teaser + '</p>' + '</span>';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('content').html(output);
    });

}

$('#btnSearch').click(function() {
    Cargardata();
});

$('#search').keypress(function(e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        Cargardata();
        return false;
    }
});
```